# fail to execute php-cgi for google app engine under windows

Tags: google-app-engine, php

OS: windows 8
google app engine sdk 1.8.2

```
C:\google_appengine>dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=D:\php5417 D:\helloworld
INFO     2013-08-03 16:13:43,874 sdk_update_checker.py:244] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-08-03 16:13:45,128 sdk_update_checker.py:260] Update check failed: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
WARNING  2013-08-03 16:13:45,148 api_server.py:314] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-08-03 16:13:45,164 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:9024
INFO     2013-08-03 16:13:45,171 dispatcher.py:164] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
ERROR    2013-08-03 16:13:45,176 php_runtime.py:216] The PHP runtime is not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php_runtime.py", line 212, in new_instance
    self._check_environment(php_executable_path)
  File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php_runtime.py", line 156, in _check_environment
    env={})
  File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\safe_subprocess.py", line 61, in start_process
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 5] 存取被拒。
INFO     2013-08-03 16:13:45,177 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: Show some of your code.  Specifically, include your app.yaml.  Looks like you are trying to run php using the python runtime.

Answer (score 2):

--php_executable_path should point to the actual executable file.  So you probably want something like:

```
--php_executable_path=D:\php5417\php-cgi.exe
```

Comment: you are right! i think google should have name a more proper variable.